# Ho can I store data in dictionary with specific keys

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Below is the sample code snippet I have been trying.

For example

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict = []
new_dict = {}

student_id = input("Enter id: ")
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
course = raw_input("Enter course: ")
school = raw_input("Enter school: ")

new_dict['student_id'] = student_id
new_dict['name'] = name
new_dict['course'] = course
new_dict['school'] = school

my_dict[student_id].append( new_dict )
```

This codes generates error.

How to come up with this expected output?
The key is the student_id.

```
output = [{
    '1': {
        'student_id': '1',
        'name': 'Test Name 1',
        'course': 'Course 1',
        'school':'School 1'
    },
    '2': {
        'student_id': '2',
        'name': 'Test Name 2',
        'course': 'Course 2',
        'school': 'Schoole 2'
    },
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are mixing up list and dictionary functionality.

From your desired output it looks like you want a dictionary not a list and the last line in your example needs to change like such:

```
my_dict = {} 
new_dict = {}

student_id = input("Enter id: ") 
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
course = raw_input("Enter course: ") 
school = raw_input("Enter school: ")

new_dict['student_id'] = student_id 
new_dict['name'] = name
new_dict['course'] = course 
new_dict['school'] = school

my_dict[student_id] = new_dict
```

Comment: Thanks @user2268460

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'append' to a dictionary. You can only 'update' it.
Instead of `my_dict[student_id].append( new_dict )` try `my_dict.update(new_dict)`